# Best way to set a mask flag to data model to prevent unauthorized access

Tags: .net, wpf, security, data-binding

I am attempting to secure a few data members of a large object model so that any UI that accesses them displays some generic characters (such as ****) rather than the actual values if the UI has enabled a security flag.

This is a WPF application with data binding. I know I could create a custom control or a converter to mask the data if a the security flag is set but then everywhere a secured data memeber is displayed needs this converter or to use my custom control. I may not know all the locations the data member is used in the UI or may forget to secure one in the future so I believe this is not a great solution.

I believe a better approach is to make it so the getter of the data member checks for a flag and returns the mask characters if the security flag is set. I know which data members need to be secured so I can secure them once and all UI development now and in the future would be secured.  What I cannot come up with is a "clean" way for the UI to set a flag that the data model would use to affect a data member's getter. It occurs to me that there is a way to do this but I just cannot remember how it is done.

Please let me know if this question is too vague.

Comment: Could you use a style instead?

Comment: Would a style be any different than a converter or custom control? Wouldn't I still need to use that style on the controls that need to be masked when the security flag is set?

Comment: I haven't tried exactly what you're wanting to do, so I don't know the answer to that. My thought was to try putting it in a global resource dictionary and applying the style by specifying TargetType. No clue if that'll work.

Comment: Aside: In matters of authorization I usually lean toward making the default (false) case the secure one, e.g. the one that hides the values. Only if the authorization/authentication is completed and the flag set true would the actual values be displayed. I'd suggest you flip your bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option. Define something like this in the resource library for the application.  TargetType applies the style to all TextBox types in my example.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Secure x:Key="SecureFlag" />
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource SecureFlag}, Path=Hide}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Create a class that returns the state of the security bit. I did it like this in my test.

```
public class Secure
{
    public bool Hide { get { return true; } }
}
```

The XAML for my main window did not change...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="333"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I tried setting the Text property and unfortunately that didn't work; however, there may be a way to get the setter to overwrite the text.

One drawback to this approach is that it's only visual. Accessibility software will see the value and you may even be able to copy and paste it. So, this solution obviously needs further refinement.

Edited - added a second option...

You can further modify this example by setting the template property in the trigger's setters to something like this.

```
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                                <TextBlock>***</TextBlock>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are dozens if not hundreds of textboxes, labels and textblocks that display data throughout my app and, so far, about 14 of those that need to be secured. Those 14 controls are displaying the 5 data properties I need to secure. I would need to go to each one specifically and tell it to use this style. I would also have to tell all developers to make sure to use this style anytime they add a new control they believe might display a secured data property.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. To make my example work, you'd have to figure out a way to test the binding, see what it refers to, and then apply the controltemplate only in the cases where it's an object you want to secure and the secure bit is set. Bummer...sorry...I tried.  :$